# Unable to install devtools in R v3.4.3 in Fedora 27 due to curl compilation failed

Tags: r, devtools, fedora-27

I cannot install this R package due to compile errors. I try

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

and receive

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcurl.so when searching for -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../libcurl.so when searching for -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libcurl.so when searching for -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libcurl.so when searching for -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:6: curl.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/laur/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
```

Searching online revealed similar problems have been solved by installing libcurl-devel, but it didn't help me, and I now have multiple versions in 32 and 64-bit:

```
sudo dnf -y install libcurl libcurl-devel
```

returns

```
Package libcurl-7.55.1-9.fc27.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Package libcurl-7.55.1-10.fc27.i686 is already installed, skipping.
Package libcurl-devel-7.55.1-10.fc27.i686 is already installed, skipping.
```

I also tried to install curl-config, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libcurl.so when searching
>    for -lcurl
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

You are missing the 64bits version. `# dnf install libcurl-devel.x86_64`

libcurl-devel.x86_64 provides: /usr/bin/curl-config :64bit, /usr/lib**64**/libcurl.so , /usr/lib**64**/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your error on Fedora 27. However, maybe this will help:

> If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
>   PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
>   is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
>   R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'

From an `ANTICONF ERROR` message [here](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/425).

**EDIT**: Not related to your error message, but make sure you also run `sudo dnf -y install openssl-devel gnutls-devel`

Comment: I exported to those paths, and installed the two packages, but still same problem. Turns out I didn't have the 64-bit version of libcurl-devel installed, but only of libcurl (they're different!)

Comment: Glad you figured it out!