# R packages not getting installed due to Linux based package dependencies

Tags: r, linux, fedora

I am trying to install "devtools" and "tidyverse", however, it giving the following errors in Fedora 28. I have searched on various forums but could not fix the issue.

Can any please help. The Error message is stated below.

```
install.packages("devtools")
Installing package into ‘/home/ahsaniftikhar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘openssl’, ‘httr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/openssl_1.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1194883 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/httr_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 147593 bytes (144 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 144 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/devtools_1.13.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 486446 bytes (475 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 475 KB

* installing *source* package ‘openssl’ ...
** package ‘openssl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
 * brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’
* removing ‘/home/ahsaniftikhar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/openssl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘openssl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/ahsaniftikhar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/ahsaniftikhar/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpm6tM0n/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Did you try doing what the message says? (install openssl-devel)

Comment: @HongOoi I tried the the option suggested by you i.e. install openssl-devel but that also did not solve the issue.

Comment: Dear All, After extensive search on stackoverflow I found the following which solved the issue for me. sudo dnf -y install openssl-devel gnutls-devel

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/50139317/7209800

Comment: By default, `install.packages()` tries to compile packages from source. This often fails because of missing developer libraries. It is much better to [set up your system to receive CRAN binaries via `dnf-copr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75449961/11932936)